# A more forgiving array_intersect in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, function

`array_intersect` takes two arrays and looks for matching `===` values and returns the result. However the values in the array have to match character for character. Is there a function or a method for comparing two arrays and looking for values that **contain** similar strings instead of **equal** similar strings. Something like stripos but with `array_intersect`.

```
$array1 = array("howdyhorse", "monkeyjoe", "bill", "donkeymonkey", "carrothorse")
$array2 = array("bill", "horse", "monkeybunk", "apple", "panda")

function($array1, $array2);

Returns an array = array("bill", "horse", "monkeyjoe")
```

The order is of no particular concern.

Comment: Not that I know of, no, but that shouldn't be difficult to write yourself.

Comment: Yeah there is no function for this, you can just use a foreach loop or maybe array_filter

Comment: Well, if you can define exactly what qualifies as "similar", you can write your own intersect using one of the [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/array_uintersect) functions.

Comment: @Wiseguy, exactly, please make an answer! PHP has an incredible amount of array functions. Do not reinvent the wheel. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is running all the values of each array through something like

```
foreach( $array as $slice )
    $slice = trim( preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement ) ) ;
```

to make everything lowercase and remove spaces and special chars and then doing an array_intersect an option?

Comment: Its a start. But some strings are combined like so 'array("monkeydunk")' and the array it compares to has it as one word 'array2("monkey")'. In which case a match should be made.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_uintersect` and [similar_text](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php). `similar_text` is `O(N**3)`, so you need to write your own function if your compare similar logic is simpler.